# target element doesn't respond

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do the `left_warrper` invisible, and after the user click on the **"click me"** button, then the `left_warrper` changes to visible, but the `:target` element doesn't work for some reason

```css
.left_wrapper {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
}

:target .left_wrapper {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sidebar" style="position:absolute;right:0px;z-index:1;">click me</a>
  <div id="sidebar" class="wrapper">
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
  </div>
<a href="#" class="left_wrapper"></a>
```

It's works good Young Kyun Jin, but when i added the code to the main .html page, I made some changes, like added the `<nav>` element, now it's again doesn't work, how can I detected it?

Here's the code:

```
<nav id="menu">
<img src="Logo.png" style="position: fixed; width: 30%; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
    <a href="#sidebar"><img src="../img/menu.png" style="position: fixed; top: 22px; right: 10px;"></a>
      <div id="sidebar" class="wrapper">
          <div class="slide">
            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="left_wrapper"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.left_wrapper {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
}

:target ~ .left_wrapper {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sidebar" style="position:absolute;right:0px;z-index:1;">click me</a>
  <div id="sidebar" class="wrapper">
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
  </div>
<a href="#" class="left_wrapper"></a>
```

`:target ~ .left_wrapper`

`~` is sibling selector

Comment: Working!! Thanks!!

Comment: @iSenderSMS It's my pleasure :)

Comment: @iSenderSMS https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors